# odbc connection

Tags: mysql, odbc, jdbc-odbc

I would like to install odbc in ubuntu server 10.10 with mysql:

I did

```
sudo apt-get install libmyodbc
```

edited odbcinst.ini

```
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage = 1
```

And odbc.ini

```
[asterisk]
Description           = MySQL connection to 'spb' database
Driver                = MySQL
Database              = myDatabase
Server                = localhost
UserName              = myUser
Password              = myPAss
Port                  = 3306
Socket                = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

And try:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc$ isql asterisk
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Did I miss some step?

Comment: this question is must be in http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: add a -v to to the isql command line. Also add the username and password like this "isql -v asterisk myUser myPAss - now what does it say.

Comment: Why are you using ODBC to connect to MySQL on a localhost?

Comment: this is just an start, i want to connect to my server. Should I write my public ip in "Server"?

Comment: bohica, yours is the solution, if you posted it as answer, I will mark it as the solution

Answer (score 2):

I got a same problem. Try:

`$ SUDO isql asterisk`

Answer (score 1):

change section `Server = localhost` with `Server = 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

Did you check you have the drivers in this directory? ubuntu installed me on other directories:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
```

Or try a simbolic link